# Populate Meteor React form with existing data

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm new to React with Meteor and I'm having trouble getting a form to populate with existing data that's being loaded from a published collection. I'm successfully publishing the collection however when I try to access `profileCandidate` in the constructor `this.state` the form won't load. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Collection: `profileCandidate`

```
{
  "_id": "JGw6dTHG3RDjDQNXc",
  "userId": "fYHKGTRhZvPKCETHQ",
  "createdAt": "2017-04-25T12:05:30.449Z",
  "name": {
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe"
  }
}
```

Component: 'ProfileCandidateForm.jsx`

```
class ProfileCandidateForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: [],
      lastName: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    profileCandidate = this.state;

    Meteor.call('profileCandidate.insert', profileCandidate);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <label>
          Name:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="First name"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={this.state.lastName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Last name"
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ProfileCandidateForm.propTypes = {
  profileCandidate: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate');

  return {
    profileCandidate: ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}),
  };
}, ProfileCandidateForm);
```

Comment: Can you console.log `this.props` ?

Comment: I put `console.log(this.props)` beneath `super(props)` and it returned `Object {profileCandidate: Array(0)}`

Comment: if you console.log props in the constructor I think it's normal they are empty cause the component didn't receive props yet. Also do you expect the collection ProfileCandidate to return an empty array?

Comment: Ok, I moved the console.log beneath `render()` it returns the data `Object {profileCandidate: Array(1)}
profileCandidate
:
Array(1)
0
:
Object
createdAt
:
Tue Apr 25 2017 22:05:30 GMT+1000 (AEST)
name
:
Object
userId
:
"fYHKGTRhZvPKCETHQ"
_id
:
"JGw6dTHG3RDjDQNXc"` which is correct.

Comment: Ok from here I don't know what you really want to do. What data should populate the form? (this is what you ask in the question)

Comment: Sorry. Within that array first and last name are stored. The names should populate the form if they are avaliable.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused. There are many ways to accomplish what you looking for but you should use `ProfileCandidate.findOne({ *** something unique  like _id*** })` otherwise the return of `find().fetch()` is an array. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've changed it to `findOne` and it appears to be an object. I'm still not sure how I get it to populate the form. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer buried deep on the meteor [forum site](https://forums.meteor.com/t/findone-dose-not-work-as-expected/29467/6).  findOne is not available when the page first loads as a result it errors. To fix this you have to return an empty object. To populate the form you need to load the prop in the parent file `App.jsx` and pass the prop over to the child file `ProfileCandidateForm.jsx`.

Component Child: 'ProfileCandidateForm.jsx`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import { ProfileCandidate } from '../api/profileCandidate/profileCandidate.js';


export default class ProfileCandidateForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var profileCandidate = this.props.profileCandidate;
    var firstName = profileCandidate && profileCandidate.name && profileCandidate.name.first;
    var lastName = profileCandidate && profileCandidate.name && profileCandidate.name.last;

    this.state = {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <label>
          Name:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="First name"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={this.state.lastName}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="Last name"
        />
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ProfileCandidateForm.propTypes = {
  profileCandidate: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

Component Parent: 'App.jsx`

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { ProfileCandidate } from '../../api/profileCandidate/profileCandidate.js';

import ProfileCandidateForm from '../ProfileCandidateForm.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        hideCompleted: false,
      };
    }

  renderProfileCandidateForm() {
    let profileCandidate = this.props.profileCandidate;
    return (
      <ProfileCandidateForm
        key={this.props.profileCandidate._id}
        profileCandidate={profileCandidate}
      />
    )
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          {this.renderProfileCandidateForm()}    
        </div>
      );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
  profileCandidate: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('profileCandidate');


  return {
    profileCandidate: ProfileCandidate.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId()}) || {},
  };
}, App);
```